# Opencv: image, retrieved from camera capture is always gray

Tags: opencv

I am always getting a grey screen when showing image using opencv, the image is captured from camera.

```
capture = cvCaptureFromCAM(-1);
cvGrabFrame(capture);
image = cvRetrieveFrame(capture);
cvShowImage("name", image);
```

after  this I see the grey screen, even if I do in cycle. But the same code works well on another computer. What is the problem? The same opencv library version is used on both computers. Working in the Visual Studio 2010, C++
Opencv version 2.2.0

EDIT 1: The camera used in both computers is the same.
And I have tried to rebuild the opencv on the computer where the problem happens, it didn't help.

Comment: You should try with device index = 0, just an idea..

Comment: Tried it, didn't help. Actually the camera is working I see the blue light indicator on it is turned on. The problem is somewhere in opencv I suppose.

Comment: as explained here: http://opencv.willowgarage.com/documentation/reading_and_writing_images_and_video.html, when using RetrieveFrame, you first call GrabFrame. The alternative is to use the single call QueryFrame.

Comment: @crisbia Sorry, I have updated the question. Actualy I do call cvGrabFrame each time before retrieving it from camera. Just by some reason didn't put the it in the code above.

Answer (score 5):

I had the same problem in OpenCvSharp. I don't know what's the cause, but for some reason, calling the "WaitKey" method after displaying the image solved it.

```
CvCapture mov = new CvCapture(filepath);
IplImage frame = mov.QueryFrame();
CvWindow win1 = new CvWindow(window name);
win1.ShowImage(frame);
CvWindow.WaitKey(1);
```

Comment: The system needs time to draw the image to the window, without the extra delay added by WaitKey you are drawing something new so fast the actual display can't keep up.

Comment: that really seems to sovle the issue for me too, even a time.sleep would not resolve this

Answer (score 1):

Your problem sounds very weird.

Try to use cvQueryFrame instead of cvRetrieveFrame() and let me know if it does make a difference.

Here is a code of using opencv for face detection, the concept of capturing an image is very similar:

```
int main( int argc, const char** argv )
{
CvCapture* capture;
Mat frame;
 //-- 1. Load the cascades
if( !face_cascade.load( face_cascade_name ) ){ printf("--(!)Error loading\n"); return -1; };
 if( !eyes_cascade.load( eyes_cascade_name ) ){ printf("--(!)Error loading\n"); return -1; };

 //-- 2. Read the video stream
 capture = cvCaptureFromCAM( -1 );
if( capture )
{
while( true )
{
  frame = cvQueryFrame( capture );

  //-- 3. Apply the classifier to the frame
  if( !frame.empty() )
   { detectAndDisplay( frame ); }
  else
   { printf(" --(!) No captured frame -- Break!"); break; }
  
  int c = waitKey(10);
  if( (char)c == 'c' ) { break; } 

} 
}return 0; 
}
```

Comment: Sorry, but cvQueryFrame didn't help.